# String to Long comparison throws "ELException: Cannot convert" in Tomcat 7, works in Tomcat 6

Tags: jsp, tomcat7, el

The following snippet works fine in Tomcat 6,

```
<c:set var="abc" value="$12,345" />
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${abc ne 0}">
        <c:out value="PASS"></c:out>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:out value="FAIL"></c:out>
    </c:otherwise> 
</c:choose>
```

but throws exception in Tomcat 7.

```
javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert $1,2345 of type class java.lang.String to class java.lang.Long
    at org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToNumber(ELSupport.java:304)
    at org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToNumber(ELSupport.java:283)
    at org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.equals(ELSupport.java:143)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstNotEqual.getValue(AstNotEqual.java:40)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:1026)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.web.statussummary.status_005fsummary_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fwhen_005f0(status_005fsummary_jsp.java:290)
```

Looks like there is a difference in the way the expression `${abc ne 0}` is evaulted in Tomcat 7. In Tomcat 6 both `${abc}` and `${0}` are compared as Strings but in Tomcat 7 I get this exception. I do not know why this should happen and which class file of which API is responsible for this.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are trying to compare a string to an int.  Per the [EL docs](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/expression-language/4.0/jakarta-expression-language-spec-4.0.html#a-eqne-b), section 1.9.2:

> #### 1.9.2 `A {==,!=,eq,ne} B`
>
> - If `A==B`, apply operator
> - If `A` is `null` or `B` is `null` return `false` for `==` or `eq`, `true` for `!=` or `ne`
> - If `A` or `B` is `BigDecimal`, coerce both `A` and `B` to `BigDecimal` and then:
>
>   - If operator is `==` or `eq`, return `A.equals(B)`
>   - If operator is `!=` or `ne`, return `!A.equals(B)`
> - If `A` or `B` is `Float` or `Double` coerce both `A` and `B` to `Double`, apply operator
> - If `A` or `B` is `BigInteger`, coerce both `A` and `B` to `BigInteger` and then:
>
>   - If operator is `==` or `eq`, return `A.equals(B)`
>   - If operator is `!=` or `ne`, return `!A.equals(B)`
> - If `A` or `B` is `Byte`, `Short`, `Character`, `Integer`, or `Long` coerce both `A` and `B` to `Long`, apply operator
> - If `A` or `B` is `Boolean` coerce both `A` and `B` to `Boolean`, apply operator
> - If `A` or `B` is an enum, coerce both `A` and `B` to enum, apply operator
> - If `A` or `B` is String coerce both `A` and `B` to `String`, compare lexically
> - Otherwise if an error occurs while calling `A.equals(B)`, error
> - Otherwise, apply operator to result of `A.equals(B)`

The problem with your test is that you are trying to compare `"$12,345"` (String) with `0` (Integer).  Since `0` is an Integer, it falls into the bold ***If*** in their docs (above), where ***A or B*** is an Integer.  Both are trying to be forced into a Long, which Java won't convert the String value `"$12,345"` into a long.  If you change your code to either of the following you will see that it works:

String comparison:

```
<c:set var="abc" value="$12,345" />
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${abc ne '0'}"> <!-- Change Integer to String -->
        <c:out value="PASS"></c:out>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:out value="FAIL"></c:out>
    </c:otherwise> 
</c:choose>
```

Integer comparison:

```
<c:set var="abc" value="12345" /> <!-- Change String to Integer -->
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${abc ne 0}">
        <c:out value="PASS"></c:out>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:out value="FAIL"></c:out>
    </c:otherwise> 
</c:choose>
```